# How to navigate by clicking with your cursor in Unix?

Tags: emacs, mouse

So when I am writing in Unix in the emacs editor it is not possible to change lines I wrote before by clicking on that particular part. Now I have to use my arrows on the keyboard and that takes a lot of time. Anyone suggestions?

Comment: It's not very clear what you mean. Please consider providing a step-by-step recipe to reproduce what you're trying to describe, starting from `emacs -Q` (no init file).

Comment: Emacs provides many different kinds of keyboard-oriented motion commands besides using the arrow keys to move one character (or line) at a time.  You can move by word, sentence, paragraph, page, or balanced expression.  You can also use isearch (`C-s` and `C-r`) to jump to arbitrary positions elsewhere in the buffer.  Third-party libraries like [avy](https://github.com/abo-abo/avy) provide additional efficient ways to move by keyboard.  None of which is what you're asking for, but you should be aware that you have many other options without resorting to the mouse.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're asking about using a mouse in a terminal.  If so, use [`xterm-mouse-mode`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/252995/how-can-mouse-support-be-enabled-in-terminal-emacs) by running `M-x xterm-mouse-mode` or adding `(xterm-mouse-mode 1)` to your `init.el`.